# Can I search between two dates in SQL using DATE_TRUNC and INTERVAL?

Tags: sql

Here is what I have working:

```sql
select  date_trunc('hour', 123.created_at) AS trunc_created_at
FROM 123abc 123
WHERE 123.expires_at > date_trunc('day', GETDATE()) + INTERVAL '2 days'
```

Is it possible, from here, to then do an 'and' or 'between' to do something like

```sql
and 123.expires_at < date_trunc('day', GETDATE()) + INTERVAL '28 days'
```

Obviously, that doesn't work, but is there a way to do this using number of days instead of a specific date? I'm pretty new to SQL and have been playing with this for 30 minutes, including a dozen google queries, and can't seem to find a way to make something like this work. Only using between and a specific date range.

Comment: `123` is an invalid identifier, and expected to raise an error when used as table alias. Which dbms are you using? (date_trunc, and date_trunc are also product specific functions.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to look back 28 days you can just subtract that from GETDATE

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() - 28 AS DATE)
```

So if you wanted to look back 28 days it would be something like this

```
SELECT
*
FROM TABLE
WHERE 1=1
AND DATE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() - 28
```

Comment: I'm more looking on how to do "between 2 and 28 days *before today* without needing to edit a timestamp. I can search older or younger than a certain date that way, but I can't figure out how to do between two dates that way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do what I wanted

`WHERE 123.expires_at > (date_trunc('day', GETDATE()) + INTERVAL '2 days') AND 123.expires_at < (date_trunc('day', GETDATE()) + INTERVAL '21 days')`

Comment: It isn't a real identifier, it's an anonymizing identifier for purposes of sharing here.